# How to check if a point is with in tolerance of another point inside a same circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was trying to build a function that return points that are within in tolerance of other points.

I have a circle and have some points inside a circle. All these points have tolerance circles. I was trying to find if there is any points which is inside tolerance circle of these individual points. For better understanding I am attaching a drawing.

[Circle with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvAsp.png)

I am trying to find if red point is on or inside tolerance circle of green point.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried for your problem ?

Comment: @coyote I had radius and angle of these points from main circle. but I am stuck with how I can check if red point is within tolerance circle of green point.

Comment: do you know how to do it mathematically?

Comment: Just calculate the distance between the two points and compare it with the radius?

Comment: @Karina No I am stuck on how to achieve that mathematically

Comment: Ohh yes that will do the trick. I will try @trincot

Comment: Then I think it is not a programming question, but a math question instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it concerns geometry, not programming specifically.

Comment: you can submit a new question when you solved the mathematics part and have problem with the programming part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the two points (x1, y1) and (x2,y2), then distance between them is:

dist = square root of (x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2.

If the radius of the tolerance is smaller than this distance, it is inside the tolerance circle.

Answer (score -1):

My idea: Coordinates, each point has (x,y),you need to calculate do distance between two points (there is mathematical formula for it) is greater then sum of their radius (of their tolerance circles).